# Apache Camel with JBoss Fuse 6.2 failed to execute goal org.apache.camel:camel-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, jboss, apache-camel, maven-3, jbossfuse

When trying to execute JBoss Fuse 6.2 based project (Local camel context) it's throwing error as below:

**Failed to execute goal org.apache.camel:camel-maven-plugin:2.15.1.redhat-621084:run**

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.camel:camel-maven-plugin:2.15.1.redhat-621084:run (default-cli) on project ncbs-cust: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.camel:camel-maven-plugin:2.15.1.redhat-621084:run failed: Plugin org.apache.camel:camel-maven-plugin:2.15.1.redhat-621084 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.camel:camel-maven-plugin:jar:2.15.1.redhat-621084 -> org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-impl:jar:2.0.5 -> org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-site-renderer:jar:1.0 -> org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.5 -> commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1.redhat-7: Failed to read artifact descriptor for commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1.redhat-7: Could not find artifact org.apache.commons:commons-parent:pom:22-redhat-2 in release.fusesource.org (http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases) -> [Help 1]

Comment: Have you added apache commons to your pom?

Comment: Could you please add your POM.xml?

Answer (score 2):

Adding another Plugin Repository for Red Hat resolved the issue.

```
<pluginRepository>
  <id>redhat</id>
  <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/</url>
  <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </releases>
</pluginRepository>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-parent</artifactId>
   <version>22-redhat-2</version>
   <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

in my Artifactory server cache from `http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/`.  I just looked, however, and it is no longer there.

Does changing the version for the `camel-maven-plugin`:

```
<parent>
   <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-plugins</artifactId> 
   <version>2.15.1.redhat-621107</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

help?

- Doug